# Can not perform DML Operation inside a query? While trying to fetch data from collection

Tags: plsql

[image]

here is my PLSQL code:

```
declare
headerStr     varchar2(1000):='C1~C2~C3~C5~C6~C7~C8~C9~C10~C11~C12~C16~C17~C18~C19~RN';
mainValStr   varchar2(32000):='1327~C010802~9958756666~05:06AM~NO~DISPOSAL~NDL~4~P32~HELLO~U~28-OCT-2017~28-OCT-2017~Reject~C010741~1;1328~C010802~9958756666~06:07AM~MH~DROP~NDL~1~P32~~U~28-OCT-2017~28-OCT-2017~Reject~C010741~2;1329~C010802~9999600785~01:08AM~BV~DROP~NDL~2~P32~MDFG~U~28-OCT-2017~28-OCT-2017~Reject~C010741~3';
valStr       varchar2(4000);
headerCur     sys_refcursor;
mainValCur   sys_refcursor;
  valCur        sys_refcursor;
header     varchar2(1000);
  val           varchar2(1000);
iterator   number:=1000;
  strIdx        number;
  strLen        number;
  idx           number;
  TYPE T_APPROVAL_RECORD IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(1000);
  headerTable T_APPROVAL_RECORD;
  cnt number;
begin
     open headerCur for select * from table(split_str(headerStr,'~'));    
     open mainValCur for select * from table(split_str(mainValStr,';'));
     loop
       fetch mainValCur into valStr; 
         exit when mainValCur%notfound; 
     insert into header_test values(cnt, valStr); -- for testing purpose
         open valCur for select * from table(split_str(valStr,'~'));
         loop
             fetch valCur into val;
             fetch headerCur into header;
             exit when valCur%notfound;
             exit when headerCur%notfound;
             insert into header_test values(header, val);
             headerTable(header):= val;
         end loop;
        idx := headerTable.FIRST; -- Get first element of array

    WHILE idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
      insert into header_test values (idx, headerTable(idx));
      idx := headerTable.NEXT(idx); -- Get next element of array
    END LOOP;
    headerTable.delete;
  end loop;
  commit;  
end;
```

c1 c2 ..... c19 are column name and RN is rownumber,

data for the columns of each will be in mainValString seperated by ;

Why i am getting ORA-14551 when i am trying to access collection "headerTable"?

Please help.

Comment: if i comment these lines code compiles without any error--                                                      idx := headerTable.FIRST; -- Get first element of array

    WHILE idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
      insert into header_test values (idx, headerTable(idx));
      idx := headerTable.NEXT(idx); -- Get next element of array
    END LOOP;
    headerTable.delete;

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line.

```
idx := headerTable.FIRST;
```

The index of `headertable` is of TYPE `VARCHAR2` whereas `idx` is defined as `NUMBER`.

declare  `idx` as `VARCHAR2(1000)`, it should work.

Having said that, `ORA-14551 - Cannot perform DML ...` is not related to this error. It is unclear to me why should you encounter this error.

Comment: i fixed that but still the same issue.

Comment: @GunjanSharma : Does your `split_str` function have any DML operation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i fixed that but still the same issue.

One other point is- if mainValCur returns 1 row the same program works fine.

Why this is happening. ??

Comment: No it does not have any dml operation...

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SPLIT_STR" (acc_str IN VARCHAR2,sep IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN tableStrSplit PIPELINED

Comment: IS
v_str varchar2(30000);
v_acc varchar2(2000);
v_str_len pls_integer;
v_msg varchar2(500);
BEGIN
    v_str:= acc_str;
    LOOP
         v_str_len := instrb ( v_str , sep);
         EXIT WHEN( v_str_len = 0 OR v_str IS NULL);
         v_acc := substrb ( v_str , 1 , v_str_len );
         v_str := substrb ( v_str , v_str_len+1 );
         PIPE ROW(RTRIM(v_acc,sep ));
         END LOOP ;
         PIPE ROW(RTRIM (v_str));
         RETURN;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
v_msg:=sqlcode||sqlerrm;
insert into err_data_transfer values('SPLIT_STR',v_msg,sysdate,null);
END split_str;

Comment: @GunjanSharma :   Ah... It does have a DML. There is an insert statement - "`INSERT INTO err_data_transfer..`" . You cannot call a function in a select statement which has DML.

Comment: That was in the case of exception.. which was not there. The same prog runs if there is only 1 row in mainHeader.
i.e.
mainValStr   varchar2(32000):='1327~C010802~9958756666~05:06AM~NO~DISPOSAL~NDL~4~P32~HELLO~U~28-OCT-2017~28-OCT-2017~Reject~C010741~1';

Comment: it looks fine If we run the code after commenting these lines.. 
idx := headerTable.FIRST; -- Get first element of array

    WHILE idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
      insert into header_test values (idx, headerTable(idx));
      idx := headerTable.NEXT(idx); -- Get next element of array
    END LOOP;
    headerTable.delete;

Comment: It is hard to figure out without the data and table  structure available to me. Probably, you will have to figure out by trial and error.commenting and uncommenting the lines and checking the exact line that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Oh but it does:

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  v_msg:=sqlcode||sqlerrm; 
  insert into err_data_transfer values('SPLIT_STR',v_msg,sysdate,null);
```

It may only be during an exception, but it's still DML during a select statement. You may be able to create another procedure as an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` to create the error log. Also, you should either re-raise or `raise_application_error` afterward. If not your procedure will continue as though the error did not occur; which leads to more problems as to why your main process does not work (including running to completion but doing the wrong thing).